# Stop video playing when presentModalView in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios4, xcode4

I have to play video in `UIWebview` using HTML string in one `ViewController`.

Now, I am Present another modal view controller using this

```
[self presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES];
```

then, new view controller is open but video is playing continue.
So, how to stop this video when I am present another modal view controller.

Here, I play video in `UIWebView`.

tell me if any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

```
[self presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES];
```

is deprecated and preferred way to do is

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
```

As you can see, you will have control over what to do once the view controller is presented. In the completion block, you can put the code to pause the video.

Answer (score 0):

The parent view controller that presented the modal will receive `viewWillDisappear`, so you can do whatever cleanup you desire, such as pausing the video. Then just respond correctly when the modal is dismissed.